# How can I make a classifier that adapts to increasing number of classes in the dataset. How many nodes should I use as output?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, deep-learning, softmax

How can I make a classifier that adapts to an increasing number of classes in the dataset.

- How many nodes should I use as output?
- If I use a softmax I need to specify the classes but if the classes increase, how can I still use part of the pre-trained architecture and make it learn more classes?
- Is adding nodes or using redundancy in the output layer the best choices?

Comment: Is there a max number of classes?

Comment: Yes. But if the number of classes is very big, should I just use a classifier with the initial number of nodes equal to the max value of classes?

Comment: I don't see other way around.